# file1.xml file2.xml in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website in php.

I generate my xml files like this:

```
file1.xml
file2.xml
file3.xml
...
```

myhtaccess

```
RewriteRule ^file\.xml$ file.php [L]
```

so when I type file.xml it opens file.php.

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
file5.xml -> file.php?n=5
```

I want to get the number after file `file7.xml` and send it to php like `file.php?n=7`

Comment: RewriteRule ^file(.*)\.xml$ file.php?n=$1 [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteRule ^file([0-9]+)\.xml$ file.php?n=$1 [L]
```

This will internally redirect **/fileNumber.xml** to **/file.php?n=number** .

Comment: Replace `+` with `*` in the capture group if you also want to access `/file.xml` uri .